# Outlook 2010 and Add-in-Express: how to make plugin collapsible when docked on one of sides of main window?

Tags: add-in, outlook-addin

I'm using Add-in-Express to develop a prototype of our plugin for Outlook and what I really would like to have is possibility to collapse/expand plugin form when it is docked directly inside main Outlook window. I suspect that Outlook VSTO API is not allowing to do such thing and probably Add-In-Express can't do it either but maybe somebody knows some hack that could be of help.

To clarify technical side of my situation:

- I have ADXOIFormsManager with one ADXOlForm
- ADXOlForm has property ExplorerLayout set to "RightReadingPane"
- ADXOlForm has property ExplorerAllowedDropRegions set to "RightReadingPane;DockRight"

Now, when Outlook starts plugin has a collapse/expand button and it works. But if I drag plugin to the second allowed dock region that is basically right side of main window button disapears.

So, is it possible to force somehow collapse/expand functionality for my plugin regardless of docking region or that's just a way it is and I have to accept it? If the latter is true how it is possible that for example Xobni plugin does it? Do they manipulate Outlook's windows on WinApi level and change their sizes to work with Xobni or they just simulate that behavior and just change plugin size to look like it was minimized in similar way 
To-Do Bar is?

**UPDATE**
I know that according to what Add-in-Express team says on their forum and in docs it is limitation of VSTO API but I'd like to know if maybe somebody hack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, diggin' through google ensured me that what I wanted to do can't be done directly with Add-In-Express API so I chose to cheat a little and simulate needed behavior.

So, what I did:

- property IsDragDropAllowed set to false
- property AlwaysShowHeader set to false
- at top of my form added panel with button which acts as a expand/collapse switch
- minimal width of plugin is limited by VSTO to 74 so that's width in "collapsed" state of plugin
- when plugin is collapsed panel with button changes its docking to left and acts as clickable bar just like in Outlook To-Do Bar
- since I disabled drag and drop I had to add to ribbon View tab my own button to allow user to change place where plugin is displayed which is fine for my project

Of course I had to fix some layout problems with controls when switching between expand and collapse state but basically I have what I wanted: Add-In-Express based plugin with expand/collapse functionality regardless of place where plugin is docked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're an Add-in Express customer, ask your question to their support. They are really experts in all things concerning their product and the connected issues of the Office environment. (I've got my calls always answered with competence).

But please be aware that Add-in Express understands itself as a **"Rapid Development Product"**, to allow Office developers to create high-level add-ins with best practices and in an exceptable time frame. On the other hand, if you have a developer team with 5 members having all a lot of C++ experience, you can produce high-level stuff with Windows Explorer and Office - you mention Xnobi, I can mention add-ins in the DMS environment, like OpenText eDocs. This is not developed using Add-in Express (I guess :-))

Comment: well, I am their client but I saw couple of similar questions on their forum and always answer was "can't be done, that's custom task pane limitation" that's why I asked here. and you are right, my intentions are little over RAD :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem wich you run into is caused by the fact that the two panes (meaning panes in the positions mentioned in your example) are based on two different technologies. Although the two panes have a similar look, one of them is an Add-in Express pane subclassing Outlook windows to make room for itself; another one is provided by Office, Custom Task Pane is its name. That said, the issue has no resolution.

Comment: well, old plain 'do it yourself' is an answer, I know because I did it. maybe it is not pretty, maybe it is not made according to what Add-in Express people had in mind but it works. and I don't mind a little hacking, I just needed to know if there really is no other way.